# How to impliment parallax scroll with raffael js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, raphael, parallax

I am following  http://www.tedxguc.com/ as a reference point, for my current project. I have managed to create paths and moving objects on these paths using raphael js library. I am being able to execute the movement of the objects on mouse click or on mouse movement. Please suggest how could I make these animations on scroll(parallax).

```
 var p = new Raphael(0,0,"100%","100%");
 p.addGuides();

 var path; 
 var path1 = p.path("M 630 180 l -420 -120").attr({opacity:0});
 image1: p.image().attr({
      "x":630,
     "y":180,
    "width": 20,
    "height": 20,
    "src": "images/image1.png"
   })};

    $(document).on("mousemove", function(){
      // animate along a path
      obj.image1.attr({
        guide : path1,
        along : 0,
        x     : 0,
        y     : 0,

      })
       .animate({along : 1}, 1000);

    });
```

Comment: With this much info and with no demo, not sure you will get answer.

Comment: Code added for your reference.

Comment: I think you will need to post a jsfiddle with some working bits in it, and the specific problem you are having. Otherwise I would do a search on Stackoverflow for Parallax, as there's quite a few helpful posts around already.